# Using OpenGL inside an android.app.Fragment

Tags: c#, android, opengl-es-2.0, xamarin

For my app, I was hoping to add an GLSurfaceView to one of my swipe-able fragments inside my Fragment Activity. I was under the impression that they worked just like ordinary view, leading me to trying the following code.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                                  ViewGroup container, 
                                  Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    rootView = 
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.VisualisationFragment, container, false);

    var fragmentLayout = 
        rootView.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.fragmentLayout);

    surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this.Activity.BaseContext);
    fragmentLayout.AddView(surfaceView);

    return rootView;
}
```

The code compiles fine and seems fine when I step through the code, until somewhere after the rootView is returned, at which point I get a 'Force Close' alert, without an exception. The GLSurface view takes up most the screen, except for a title at the top and a button at the bottom. I've declared the use of OpenGL in my manifest, is there any other configuration I'm missing?

My question:

Is it possible to use OpenGL *inside* a Fragment *inside* a FragmentActivity and if so, how do I assign my surfaceView to my rootView without my application exploding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ouch, talk about an unfortunate conflict of terms... Fragment has its own meaning in OpenGL, so half of this question sounds like gibberish.

Comment: I corrected the title so you might get some hits.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got this working earlier, to little avail because it was too laggy to prove useful.

To fix it, the renderer WAS required, and needed to inherit from Java.Lang.Object as well as IRenderer to allow you to implement the Handler property.

Destroying and recreating the GlSurfaceView on every swipe proved too much processing power to keep a consistently smooth swipe between panels though on, thats even when the OnSurfaceCreate and OnSurfaceDestroy methods were empty.